# Unable to upgrade clamav due to dependency weirdness

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I'm trying to upgrade my clamav installation to the latest version (0.95.2).  I am running CentOS 5.3, and I have rpmforge added.

The command I am using is

```
yum upgrade clam*
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: clamav = 0.95.1-4.el5.rf for package: clamd
---> Package clamav.x86_64 0:0.95.2-4.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package clamav-db.x86_64 0:0.95.2-4.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
clamd-0.95.1-4.el5.rf.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: clamav = 0.95.1-4.el5.rf is needed by package clamd-0.95.1-4.el5.rf.x86_64 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: clamav = 0.95.1-4.el5.rf is needed by package clamd-0.95.1-4.el5.rf.x86_64 (installed)
```

So it's complaining that 0.95.1-4.el5.rf is missing, but as far as I can tell it's not:

```
# rpm -qa | grep clam
clamav-0.95.1-4.el5.rf
clamd-0.95.1-4.el5.rf
clamav-db-0.95.1-4.el5.rf
```

Any tips at this point would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same set up as you and the same problem.  What yum is saying is that there is a new clamav and clamdb, but if it goes ahead with the upgrade it will break clamd (currently installed) which depends on the old clamav.  The solutions is to hold off on the upgrade until a new clamd (which will be dependent on the new clamav) is released.  Try again tomorrow.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because, although everyone had great suggestion, I think this answer really nailed the cause of the problem.  I think yum's error message was extreamly confusing so I'd like to thank Hector for demystifying what was happening. 
 
Needless to say that today the new clamd package was made available and upgrading works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need clamd running you can do 'rpm -e clamd', then your clamav upgrade should go fine.

If you need clamd, check to see if there is an updated clamd rpm. You could also uninstall clamd, run the upgrade, and try to reinstall it. It is possible there is an updated clamd but maybe it is not in the repository.

Since the versions look like they all mix, not sure why it is erroring but rpm is weird like that sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your local yum data.

I think it's :

`yum clear all`

`man yum` to be sure.

Another thing to check is the arch of the "missing" dependency.
Make sure it is the same as the pckage you are trying to install/update:

e.g.

`rpm -q --queryformat "%{name}.%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}\\n" clamav`

Answer (score 1):

The new clamd is available for update today, so you will be able to upgrade successfully now using the same command as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install and then reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to manually copy the clamd rpm to the box and just do a force install ignoring dependencies:

`rpm -iv --nodeps --force clamd-0.95.1-4.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

CentOS has released an updated clamd that resolves this dependency issue. Try your update again and It Should Work(tm).